# Как убрать "preview" опцию Win 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

Здравствуйте. У меня "Win 7 Максимальная" версия, и когда открываю много папок, то в панели задач появляются значки папки. И когда наведу на них курсор, то показывает предварительную версию, вроде как маленькими окошками. Вопрос, как убрать эту опцию, чтобы только при нажатии показывались эти окошки - предварительные, а не при наведении курсора.![alt text][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpq4I.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, это вам нужно установить флажок в опциях в свойствах папки "Всегда отображать значки, а не эскизы". Подробнее здесь: [изменение вида и поведения папки](http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-vista/Change-folder-views-and-behavior).